# Thread-safe invoke on NET CF

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, compact-framework

I have a background thread running that fires events, but how can I ensure a thread safe invocation of these events using NET CF?

I would use ISyncronizeInvoke on the NET platform, but I can't find this on NET CF. I'm sure there are an equivalent available.... or?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Compact Framework *does* have `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`, although I believe it's limited to the `EventHandler` delegate (with any other delegate throwing an exception at execution time).

Assuming your *actual* instance of `ISynchronizeInvoke` is going to be a UI control, I'd just pass the reference as `Control` to whatever needs it. If you *really* want to use an interface, you could always create your own `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface, and then an implementation which just wraps `Control`.

Comment: Correct, the CF does have Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke/InvokeRequired. But the are introduced in class Control, no Interface.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is available in .NET CF, here is an extract from such a project:

*SampleMethod()* is called from another thread.

```
delegate void SimpleInvokeDelegate();
private void SampleMethod()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new SimpleInvokeDelegate(SampleMethod));
    }
    else
    {
       // Update UI elements here.
    }
}
```