# Setting a label text from data off a thread using .Net Compact/Windows CE

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I can't seem to find a solid source of information on how to do this. A breakdown of what I'm doing. I have a server/client running, which runs on a thread. Once information is received I need to put that information into a label.

To be fully clear, the messageReceived I want to display in a label.

Code from my listen class:

```
        public void receiveMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //read from client
        int bytesRead;
        try
        {
            lock (_client.GetStream())
            {
                bytesRead = _client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
                //Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead));
            }
            //if client has disconnected
            if (bytesRead < 1)
                return;
            else
            {
                //get the message sent
                string messageReceived =
                    ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);   
                if (frmMain.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    frmMain.UpdateData(messageReceived);
                }
            }
            //continue reading from client
            lock (_client.GetStream())
            {
                _client.GetStream().BeginRead(
                    data, 0, _client.ReceiveBufferSize,
                    receiveMessage, null);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Code from the frmMain.UpdateData:

```
        public void UpdateData(string text)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateData), new object[] { text });
            return;
        }
        stat_bar.Text = text;
    }
```

This works fine on a normal desktop win forms application. But I need to make something work within WindowsCE/.NetCompact framework.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383372/9453080)

Comment: That answer has me updating in the else {}, which when I do it skips the else statement. Any tips there?

Comment: Did you tried calling it with a `delegate`? `private delegate void UpdateDataDelegate(string text);` and `this.Invoke(new UpdateDataDelegate(UpdateData), text);`

Comment: I'm also wondering if `new object[] { text }` is a valid argument for your method, because the second parameter of `Invoke` is `params object[] args` it makes me think that `UpdateData` is receiving `object[] { object[] { text } }`. If you put a breakpoint in the `stat_bar.Text = text;` line, does it hits?

Answer (score 0):

To update a GUI element from another, non-GUI, thread, you need to use a Delegate and Invoke. I always use this pattern:

```
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public void addLog(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(addLog);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            if (txtLog.Text.Length > 2000)
                txtLog.Text = "";
            txtLog.Text += text + "\r\n";
            txtLog.SelectionLength = 0;
            txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.Text.Length - 1;
            txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
```

You can do this with all types of arguments and elements.

Comment: This is slightly different from what I've tried, but still doesn't work. Some reason the .net compact is so different any reasonable idea doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The code above is used always in my Form (GUI thread) code. To update from a background thread, you need to add a delegate in the Thread code and eventhandler in the Form code, see also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/01/mobile-development-easy-to-use-background-thread-with-gui-update/. BTW: CF is running on devices with limitted resources, therefor the API is reduced.